# ¿Como puedo modificar la escala de tiempo de un archivo mp4 en el encabezado para obtener la duración deseada exacta en python?

Tags: python, archivo, video, struct

Estoy intentando cambiar la duración de un mp4 en python, el problema es que la duracion no me da exacta

Este codigo lo que trata es ver la escala de tiempo y determinar cuanto debe valer para que el resultado de 15 segundos

```py
import struct
with open("video.mp4","rb") as f:
  d=bytearray(f.read())
def x(a,b,c,r=False):
  """a==b
     c==x
  """
  if r:
    """a==b
       x==c
    """
    return round((c*a)/b)
  else:
    return round((c*b)/a)
scale=int.from_bytes(d[52:56], byteorder='big', signed=False)
 
duration=int.from_bytes(d[57:61],byteorder='big',signed=False)
milisegundos=15000
c=x(scale,duration,milisegundos)
d[57:57+4]=struct.pack(">i",c)
with open("outs.mp4","wb") as r:
  r.write(d)
```

al revisar la longitud dice 16:39, cuando deberia decir 00:15

¿A que se debe?

(El vídeo original es de 1:06)

si hago el proceso inverso:

```py
import struct
with open("video.mp4","rb") as f:
  d=bytearray(f.read())
def x(a,b,c,r=False):
  """a==b
     c==x
  """
  if r:
    """a==b
       x==c
    """
    return round((c*a)/b)
  else:
    return round((c*b)/a)
scale=int.from_bytes(d[52:56], byteorder='big', signed=False)
 
duration=int.from_bytes(d[57:61],byteorder='big',signed=False)
milisegundos=15000
c=x(scale,duration,milisegundos,True)
d[52:56]=struct.pack(">i",c)
with open("outs.mp4","wb") as r:
  r.write(d)
```

me devuelve 18:30:18

El segundo codigo deberia estar bien, ya que por ejemplo
scale=1000
y
duration=8000
deberia hacer la regla de 3 para obtener la escala de tiempo para 15000 milisegundos,

pero en su lugar obtengo 18 horas ¿por que?
¿por que el incorrecto se acerca mas?